# Finding all functions $f$ and $g$ satisfying $pv = f(t)$ and $\frac{v}{t} = g(p)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all functions $f,g$ satisfying
>
> $$\begin{align}pv = f(t) \\[4pt]      
>  \frac{v}{t} = g(p)\end{align}$$
> where $p,v,t$ are dependent variables.
>
> $f(t)$ is a function of $t$ alone; only $t$ terms and constants
> $g(p)$ is a function of $p$ alone; only $p$ terms and constants

My attempt:
$f(t)/g(p) = pt$
Clearly $f(t) = at$ and $g(p) = a/p$ satisfy.

Looks there aren't any other functions. But I'm not so sure. Don't know if there are some fancy functions like $f(t) = e^t*\Gamma(t), g(p) = \int_0^p e^{u^2\sin u} du$ etc...

Is there a more formal way to prove ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112934/discussion-between-soumyadwip-chanda-and-across).

Answer (score 2):

I would just rewrite your ratio of $f/g$ slightly differently, separating the variables as:
$$\frac{f(t)}t = p \cdot g(p)$$

As the LHS cannot depend on $p$, and the RHS cannot depend on $t$, the only way this can hold is if they are both a constant, say $a$.  Then it follows $f(t)= at, \quad g(p)= a/p$.

Comment: Wow! so $f(t)/t$ and $pg(p)$ are both constant. this just means $pv/t$ is constant. Neat! Thank you so much you made this really simple!

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree with @Macavity

I have just a more mathematically rigorous solution for the same proposition
[image]

Similarly you can calculate it for p